# Embedding Processing in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, processing

Is there a way to embed seamlessly Processing code into a Groovy application?

If it not exists, is there a way to do it in Java? I mean something to attach a component like a `JFrame` with the content of a processing script having possibility to exchange data between both.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to start mixing groovy and processing.org:

Add processing's core.java to classpath:

```
$ set CLASSPATH=C:\javaprograms\processing-1.2.1\lib\core.jar
```

Create a file named go.groovy, containing:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class MySketch extends PApplet {
  void setup() {
    size(480, 120);
    smooth();
  }

  void draw() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
  }
}

PApplet.main("--present", "MySketch" );
```

Run the script:

```
$ groovy go.groovy
```